# Samsung Galaxy S7562 Force application to start on power up?

Tags: applications, boot

Is there a way to force an application to start automatically on every power up on my Samsung Galaxy S7562?

Thx

Comment: Do you mean an app you have installed already, or is it possible to create an app that does this? For the first, I think you need root, and something like Startup Manager (not sure you can *add* apps to it though) and for the second, definitely.

Comment: Yes,I meant for an already installed application, like a Startup Manager.

Answer (score 0):

There are several apps capable of doing exactly that (adding other apps to the "autostart ramp"). Some of them you can find in my [Auto-Start Management](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_autostart) listing. I'd recommend you taking a look at [Autorun](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.fit009c.autorun) especially for mainly two reasons: 1) it's the best rated I've seen so far, and 2) it's pretty permission-friendly (only requesting 1 permission: to be informed when the device boot completed). Quoting the app description:

> A simple autorun service that allows you to automatically launch selected applications upon your device power up. No more missed messages because you forgot to start your favorite chat client, just setup an autorun and always be online.

For alternatives, please consult the list I've linked above ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question so quickly. Very much appreciated!

Comment: Glad I could help! If you consider this a solution to your issue, please do not forget to mark it such (click the check-mark next to the answer you chose as "preferred solution"). Enjoy!